# Jquery remove text/numbers inside of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have started learning JQuery and made script that when you press button it adds that button value into a div. I made a **CLEAR** text that when you press it clears the text / numbers from that div but the problem is when you press the **CLEAR** and i press button that should add X value into that div it does not print it and i have to refresh the page.

**CLEAR SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(".total").remove();
    });
});
```

**CLEAR TEXT**

```
<p>CLEAR</p>
```

**DIV**

```
<div id="div_number" class="total"></div>
```

EDIT:

I also have to remove `value=""` from this `Oh it can be my mistake, i also have to remove the value="" from```

EDIT 2:

This is the code that i have made [jsfiddle.net/utcs4L1h/](https://jsfiddle.net/utcs4L1h/)

Comment: Is this what you want to achieve? [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/w3mjjxyn/)

Comment: @RicardoRuiz Here is what i have done [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/utcs4L1h/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

So, based on your provided code on `jsfiddle`, you just need to add this: `count = 0;` after this: `$('.total').empty();`

```
$(".clear").click(function() {
    $('.total').empty();
    count = 0;
});
```

---

*I kept following for future readers*

You used `remove()`, instead of `empty()` or just `text('')`.

From `jQuery` documentation:

- `.remove( [selector ] )`: *Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.*
- `.empty()`: *Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM.*
- `text()`: *Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.*

Read more about [**remove()**](https://api.jquery.com/remove/), [**empty()**](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) also [**text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: Hi, here is the code that i have made [pastebin.com/U6TuAnpQ](http://pastebin.com/U6TuAnpQ) and the issue is that it removes the numbers from that `<div id="div_number" class="total"></div>` but when i want to press the button again it does not add it. I am not 100% sure if it does not delete the numbers from value="" on `<input type="hidden" name="number" id="form_number" value="">`

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle of the code that i have  [jsfiddle.net/utcs4L1h/](https://jsfiddle.net/utcs4L1h/)

Comment: @SeppoKuusela happy to help. if you like, you can mark my answer to helping future readers. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
$(".total").remove();
```

on this:

```
$(".total").html('');
```

If you want clear your div, you shouldn't remove it, but only remove its content. Use `html('')` to do this :)

Comment: Nope, i still have to refresh the page if i wan't the numbers show on the div after clearing.

Comment: Oh it can be my mistake, i also have to remove the value="" from `<input type="hidden" name="number" id="form_number" value="">`

Comment: always use `html('')` or `empty()` if you want remove content from something

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle of the code that i have [jsfiddle.net/utcs4L1h/](https://jsfiddle.net/utcs4L1h/)

Answer (score 0):

Use empty() instead of remove().

```
$('.total').empty();
```

Doesn't matter much in this simple example, but empty() is preferred to html('') since jquery will remove event handlers/etc on child nodes.

Comment: Nope, i still have to refresh the page if i wan't the numbers show on the div after clearing

Comment: Oh it can be my mistake, i also have to remove the value="" from `<input type="hidden" name="number" id="form_number" value="">`

Comment: To remove the value from that input, use $('#form_number').val('');

Comment: If you're still having problems after that, you'll need to post more of your code.

Comment: Yep still did not get it working, here it is [pastebin.com/U6TuAnpQ](http://pastebin.com/U6TuAnpQ)

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle of the code that i have  [jsfiddle.net/utcs4L1h/](https://jsfiddle.net/utcs4L1h/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2bpoujvr/ for a fixed version. You were doing a lot of little things in weird ways, so I'm not exactly sure what you were going for.  Your original $('button') click handler was applying to both buttons on the page.  You were also going to end up appending the number 1 as a string instead of incrementing the count.  Please review the differences to see what's going on now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `text()` jQuery method instead of removing your element from the DOM.

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $triggerX = $("#trigger-x"),
    $triggerClear = $("#trigger-clear"),
    $totalContainer = $("#div_number"),
    $hiddenInput = $("#form_number"),

    iNumber = 1000;

  $triggerX.on("click", function() {
    $totalContainer.text(iNumber);
    $hiddenInput.val(iNumber);
  });
  $triggerClear.on("click", function() {
    $totalContainer.text("");
    $hiddenInput.val("");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="form_number" type="number" value="" />

<button id="trigger-x">ADD #</button>
<button id="trigger-clear">CLEAR</button>

<div id="div_number" class="total"></div>
```

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle of the code that i have  [jsfiddle.net/utcs4L1h/](https://jsfiddle.net/utcs4L1h/)